# Why objects dont appear closer and smaller to a myopic person and far and larger to hypermetropic person after wearing spects?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision, biology, perception

I am a myopic person, and wear a concave lens. It is taught to us that lens I wear help to form image on my far point and thus help me to see far object.

1.But we have also learn that concave lens form diminished image, than why DOESN'T things appear smaller and closer ( as image form on my far point that is closer than actual distance of object ) to me after wearing spects but appear at original distance and height as they appear to a normal eye, vice versa for convex lens case why objects not appear larger and far, although we knew convex lens form larger and far image (between f and o) and concave lens form smaller and closer image than actual object , than why all things appear the same height and distance to a myopic and hypermetropic person after  wearing a lens(convex or concave) ?

2.Why objects appear much more smaller or shrink when i keep my spects away from my eye (large in case of convex lens)and not disturbing object's distance, if possible could you kindly please explain through a rough diagram?

3.Why things appear smaller and sharper but become OK after some days when i wear a new prescribed concave lens even of very high power?

Hope my question is clear, ask if any query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We appreciate size by the size of the image we get on the retina, and because the retina is a constant distance from our eye lens, the only thing that matters is the angle between the two ends of the object and our eye

[image]

An object and its image always have the same angle with respect to the lens center, so if the glasses lens and your eye are really close, they share a center and the angle doesn't change. However, if you separate your eye lens and glasses lens, you can show that the angle your eye sees is different the the object's original angle:
[image]

Sorry for bad drawing, if you have more questions I can try using powerpoint instead of paint to make it clearer :)

Comment: Wow.....I came to know  very much, thats why object far also appear small like small object near our eye at some specific distance!! Could you please draw and explain the last diagram please sir and yah!! What about object DISTANCE ,won't object appear closer in concave mirror than actually is! As concave lens form   virtual image closer than actual object??? Also please explain the last diagram like angle change if glasses are close to eye and far from eye as u have mentioned with a clear diagram please sir.....sorry for disturbing